# CSS @keyframes won't work cross-browser

Tags: html, css

I have this code for creating a slider image, but for some reason it won't work on both Chrome and FF, I've managed to make it work on one at a time, but not both...
here's the code:
//Works on FF atm//

```
@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
            0% { left: 0%; }
            20% { left: 0%; }
            25% { left: -100%; }
            45% { left: -100%; }
            50% { left: -200%; }
            70% { left: -200%; }
            75% { left: -300%; }
            95% { left: -300%; }
            100% { left: -400%; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes slidy {
            0% { left: 0%; }
            20% { left: 0%; }
            25% { left: -100%; }
            45% { left: -100%; }
            50% { left: -200%; }
            70% { left: -200%; }
            75% { left: -300%; }
            95% { left: -300%; }
            100% { left: -400%; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes slidy {
            0% { left: 0%; }
            20% { left: 0%; }
            25% { left: -100%; }
            45% { left: -100%; }
            50% { left: -200%; }
            70% { left: -200%; }
            75% { left: -300%; }
            95% { left: -300%; }
            100% { left: -400%; }
        }
        @keyframes slidy {
            0% { left: 0%; }
            20% { left: 0%; }
            25% { left: -100%; }
            45% { left: -100%; }
            50% { left: -200%; }
            70% { left: -200%; }
            75% { left: -300%; }
            95% { left: -300%; }
            100% { left: -400%; }
        }div#slider{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    div#slider figure img{
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
    div#slider figure{
        position: relative;
        width: 500%;
        margin: 0;
        left:0;
        font-size: 0;
        -webkit-animation: slidy 5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
        -moz-animation:    slidy 5s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
        -o-animation:      slidy 5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
        animation:         slidy 5s infinite; /* IE 10+ */
    }
```

and the html:

```
<div id="slider">
    <figure>
        <img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/headerPhoto1.png" >
        <img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/headerPhoto2.png" >
        <img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/headerPhoto3.png" >
        <img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/headerPhoto4.png" >
        <img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/headerPhoto5.png" >
    </figure>
</div>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Works on Chrome (24) for me with the same code. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbyne/).

Comment: Seems OP is using older version of Chrome.

Comment: @Jai: Doubt if that could be the case as OP says it works on one at a time.

Comment: @harry I'm using Version 35.0.1916.153 m of chrome....just checked for updates and im up-to-date

Comment: @harry Ok, plus it ain't workin on mobile chrome either...

Comment: The given example works very well in Chrome 34 and the good ol' Opera 12. What is the problem?

Comment: @feeela - the problem is that it ain't working on chrome nor chrome mobile

Comment: @Aviad Using the test-Fiddle provided above, I can however confirm that it does work in Chrome (Dekstop and Mobile!). There must be something additional on you site, that is not part of the code in the question (or the Fiddle).

Comment: @feela - try going on the following (ignore the language) : http://www.iscadb.org/crossfit   .
It is a WP theme btw...

Comment: Why don't you use `@keyframes` as well.

Comment: @alvaro - what do u mean ?

Comment: I would hate to add this as answer. But this line `//Animation for slider//` is the problem. Remove it. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbyne/1/). Same code as my previous fiddle but with this extra line and it doesn't work. In CSS, comments should typically be within `/*...*/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/8Pwkr/1/) code, I have checked in ipad2, ipad mini and ipad air, also on chrome on android mobile

```
<div id="slider">
    <figure>
        <img alt="" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" >
        <img alt="" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" >
        <img alt="" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" >
        <img alt="" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" >
        <img alt="" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" >
    </figure>
</div>
```

I think you should cross check the photos you have uploaded, if they are accessible properly.

```
<img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/headerPhoto1.png" >
```

If you have any query then please modify the jsfiddle, and resend the link.

Regards D.